# How to config WCF using local IP Address?

Tags: wcf

I want to config WCF using local IP Address.
Please help me to host WCF to IIS and edit web.config file using LOCAL IP ADDRESS
Thanks and best regards

Comment: If you use the Default configuration, you use the local ip address. What have you configured?

Comment: You may use net.tcp protocol for this. Refer this [link](http://jai-on-asp.blogspot.in/2011/11/comparison-of-various-bindings-in-wcf.html) for more details on bindings and configuration and for net.tcp, refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772(v=vs.110).aspx)